# Publishing application to WAS server getting invalid invalid header

Tags: websphere

1.While publishing application getting following application it is not allowing me to publish application. giving invalid Header exception

2.The publish encountered some problems and the application may not have been installed or it may have been successfully installed but was unable to start. View the Details to display the exceptions and server logs that occurred during the publish.

```
======== App ========

Failed to add or remove the application from the server: App
[6/23/16 14:35:58:492 EDT] 00000068 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5016I: Installation of App started.
[6/23/16 14:35:58:507 EDT] 00000068 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Rational\WAS\profiles\AppSrv02\logs\ffdc\server1_a3eaafb6_16.06.23_14.35.58.4922444272500934771801.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ValidateEE5RestrictionTask.performTask 144
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Rational\WAS\profiles\AppSrv02\logs\ffdc\server1_a3eaafb6_16.06.23_14.35.58.5072495233471069180776.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run 328
[6/23/16 14:35:58:636 EDT] 00000068 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5014E: The installation of application App failed.
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ManifestException: IWAE0015E An IOException occurred reading the manifest in archive: AppWeb-1.0.war
Stack trace of nested exception:
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
                at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:417)
                at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:211)
                at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:81)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveManifestImpl.<init>(ArchiveManifestImpl.java:81)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.makeManifest(ArchiveImpl.java:2792)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.getManifest(ArchiveImpl.java:2288)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.DeploymentProperties.loadLink(DeploymentProperties.java:1380)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.DeploymentProperties.loadFrom(DeploymentProperties.java:1359)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.DeploymentProperties.<init>(DeploymentProperties.java:1054)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.getDeploymentProperties(ArchiveImpl.java:180)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.containsEJBContent(WARFileImpl.java:1838)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForXmiFiles(AppInstallHelper.java:1372)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForXmiFiles(AppInstallHelper.java:1331)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForEE5Restrictions(AppInstallHelper.java:512)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ValidateEE5RestrictionTask.performTask(ValidateEE5RestrictionTask.java:126)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)

[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R Stack trace of nested exception:
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R java.io.IOException: invalid header field
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:417)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:211)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:81)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveManifestImpl.<init>(ArchiveManifestImpl.java:81)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.makeManifest(ArchiveImpl.java:2792)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.getManifest(ArchiveImpl.java:2288)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.DeploymentProperties.loadLink(DeploymentProperties.java:1380)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.DeploymentProperties.loadFrom(DeploymentProperties.java:1359)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.DeploymentProperties.<init>(DeploymentProperties.java:1054)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.getDeploymentProperties(ArchiveImpl.java:180)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.containsEJBContent(WARFileImpl.java:1838)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForXmiFiles(AppInstallHelper.java:1372)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForXmiFiles(AppInstallHelper.java:1331)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForEE5Restrictions(AppInstallHelper.java:512)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ValidateEE5RestrictionTask.performTask(ValidateEE5RestrictionTask.java:126)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
[6/23/16 14:35:58:523 EDT] 00000068 SystemErr     R                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Built-By: id 
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0 
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3 
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Comment: There appears to be an invalid attribute in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file of `AppWeb-1.0.war`.  Please paste the contents of that MANIFEST.MF file.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: id
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver